# How to remove statements from where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSalesByParameters] 
(   
    @firstName varchar(70),
    @lastName varchar(70),
    @dateFrom datetime,
    @dateTo datetime,
    @selectValid varchar(70),
    @selectCallCenters varchar(70)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select * from Sales 
    where valid = @selectValid
    and firstName LIKE '%'+@firstName+'%'
)
```

I'm trying to make a function that gives me all sales stored on the Sales table, but somethimes the parameter "selectvalid" can be null. If that value comes with value "", how can I do to remove it from the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `@selectValid` should be ignored when its value is an empty string, then just change this line from:

```
where valid = @selectValid
```

to

```
where (@selectValid = '' OR valid = @selectValid)
```

The question is a little ambiguous as to if `@selectValid` will be an empty string or null. If you want to handle both cases, then try:

```
where (@selectValid IS NULL OR @selectValid = '' OR valid = @selectValid)
```

Typically I use this approach, but if you are dealing with large tables or having performance issues with this approach, then you might want to read up a bit here:

- [Proper way to handle 'optional' where clause filters in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705634/proper-way-to-handle-optional-where-clause-filters-in-sql)
- [Query running longer by adding unused WHERE conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709348/query-running-longer-by-adding-unused-where-conditions/1709698#1709698)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSalesByParameters] 
(   
    @firstName varchar(70),
    @lastName varchar(70),
    @dateFrom datetime,
    @dateTo datetime,
    @selectValid varchar(70),
    @selectCallCenters varchar(70)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select * from Sales 
    where (@selectValid IS NULL OR valid = @selectValid)
    and firstName LIKE '%'+@firstName+'%'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where (valid = @selectValid
    or valid is null)
```

or

```
where (valid = @selectValid
    or @selectValid is null)
```

(Replacing is null with <> null, != null etc depending on what DBMS you are using)